# Unique identifier for every user/session in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF application and want to assign to every user, who opens it in the browser, a unique identifier.

To implement it, I want to use a global `long` variable and increment it, whenever a new user connects to the web application.

I have 2 questions:

1) Where (in which method) should I place the increment code?

2) How can I access that global variable in Java classes of the web app?

Comment: That's what the session ID is. Why would you need an additional unique identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a session id assigned for free by the appServer. To get at it in your bean code:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
String sessionId = session.getId();
```